# Fatal error on CiviEvent dashboard in 4.7 using PHP 5.3.5

Tags: civievent, error, php

Just tried the 4.7 upgrade and found it was giving a fatal error when I tried to acces either the event dashboard ( `/civicrm/event?reset=1` ) and Manage Events ( `/civicrm/event/manage?reset=1` ).

`Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function Civi\ActionSchedule\MappingInterface::createQuery() (previously declared abstract in Civi\ActionSchedule\Mapping) in C:\xampp\htdocs\switch\sites\all\modules\civicrm\Civi\ActionSchedule\Mapping.php on line 64`

I can access the other CiviEvent pages (e.g. add new event, add participant, etc), and none of the other components seem affected.

Using Drupal 7.41, and upgraded to 4.7 from 4.6.10. I am running PHP 5.3.5, which the upgrade warned against but only for future versions?

Comment: Not sure if it relates, but if so it is likely your PHP version: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66818

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to be the php version that's causing problems - updating php resolved it. I may flag up that the upgrade warning message isn't clear enough.

Comment: Great. Then I'll make my comment an "answer". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it relates, but if so it is likely your PHP version:

- [Bug #66818  PHP Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66818)